# set textarea text from ViewData asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to set textarea text after retrieving it from Facebook. I can retrieve name and write it in Sql, but can't set it in textarea.. 
Here's my textarea:

```
 @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Name, new { id = "NameBox", placeholder = "Name" })
```

I have tried this:

```
 @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Name, ViewData["name"], new { id = "NameBox", placeholder = "Name" })
```

but here's an error: no overloads for method TextAreaFor that takes 3 arguments.. 
Is there any other way to assign this value in my text area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Name,  new { id = "NameBox", placeholder = "Name", Value = ViewData["name"]})
```